# Setting the path for the root directory in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am using nginx and passenger to deploy my rails app. I followed the steps given at http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri to deploy my app to a sub uri in nginx.
However, the / in my application is still pointing to my server name, when it should rather be pointing to server_name/app_name.
Any way i can make this change ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understood the problem, in general you should double-check your root directive in nginx.conf pointing it to the 'public' directory inside your rails app

If you can give more information about the error and paste nginx.conf it should be easier to help you